# How do correct import refunds to Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I tried import data about returns to GA over data import tool in account.
csv scheme is

```
ga:transactionId,ga:productSku,ga:transactionRevenue,ga:quantityRefunded,ga:productPrice
```

Google help says i need use only transactionId for import returns data

I do it as below

```
ga:transactionId
25456
35218
and etc
```

No any errors after import, but i can't see result in account. I tried many times and wait more longer than 24 hours.

But still no success.
What i did wrong?

Comment: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6066862?hl=en

Comment: I did it as is in that instruction. But it doesn't work. Full refunds
To issue a full refund, you only need to upload Transaction ID. When a row in your upload file contains only ga:transactionId, the entire transaction, including all products, will be refunded using the originally reported product quantities, prices, and transaction revenue.